# WPF control derived from Label: are custom properties (with DP) not using the setter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties

So far all my binding have worked well, as long as they were done with existing control properties of, say, Button, Label, and so on. For a single purpose I need a custom canvas (that inherits from Canvas) with one additional property. Yet the binding doesn't seem to work there. I then created a simpler example using a custom Label that can reproduce my problem. The custom label is defined in code as follows:

```
namespace CustomCanvasTest
{
  class CustomLabel : Label
  {
    public string Str
    {
      get { return GetValue(StrProperty) as string; }
      set
      {
        SetValue(StrProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Str", typeof(string), typeof(CustomLabel));
  }
}
```

The XAML of the main window:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomCanvasTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomCanvasTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="313,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding ButtonClickCmd}"/>
        <local:CustomLabel Content="{Binding SomeString}" Str="{Binding SomeString}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="291,288,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the `ViewModel` has the following code (the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` is untouched):

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using WpfHelperClasses;

namespace CustomCanvasTest
{
  class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public ViewModel()
    {
      SomeString = "init";
    }

    private string someString;
    public string SomeString
    {
      get { return someString; }
      set
      {
        someString = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SomeString");
      }
    }

    #region INPC

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
    }

    #endregion

    public ICommand ButtonClickCmd
    {
      get
      {
        return new DelegateCommand(param =>
        {
          SomeString = "blub";
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I click on the button, the label content changes visibly, but the breakpoint I set inside the setter for `Str` is never reached. I'm surely making some newbie mistake here, but even looking around the other answers here regarding similar problems I can't quite figure it out alone. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on MSDN:

> For implementation reasons, it is computationally less expensive to
>   identify a property as a dependency property and access the property
>   system SetValue method to set it, rather than using the property
>   wrapper and its setter. This is because a XAML processor must infer
>   the entire object model of the backing code based only on knowing the
>   type and member relationships that are indicated by the structure of
>   the markup and various strings.
>
> ...
>
> Because the current WPF implementation of the XAML processor behavior
>   for property setting bypasses the wrappers entirely, you should not
>   put any additional logic into the set definitions of the wrapper for
>   your custom dependency property. If you put such logic in the set
>   definition, then the logic will not be executed when the property is
>   set in XAML rather than in code.

So the answer to your question is: No, the setter is not necessarily called.

---

In order to get notified about value changes of a dependency property, you will have to register a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) via dependency property metadata:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StrProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Str", typeof(string), typeof(CustomLabel),
        new PropertyMetadata(StrPropertyChanged));

private static void StrPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var label = obj as CustomLabel;
    var str = e.NewValue as string;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that clarifies it! That puts me in a bad spot though, since I want to subscribe an event inside the currently set property (which will then be a custom class, not a string), and I wanted to do that inside the setter. I can't do it in the constructor, since the value might not be set yet. Do you maybe have a suggestion for that? Anyway, thanks a lot for the clarity!

Comment: You might register a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UIPropertyMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uipropertymetadata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for getting values, which are assigned to your Dependency property:

> Provides property metadata for non-framework properties that do have rendering/user interface impact at the core level.

Example:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrProperty = 
                           DependencyProperty.Register("Str",
                                                       typeof(string),
                                                       typeof(CustomLabel), 
                                                       new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty, IsStrTurn));

    public string Str
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(StrProperty) as string; 
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(StrProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void IsStrTurn(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {    
        string strOld = e.OldValue as string;
        string strNew = e.NewValue as string;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The old value is " + strOld); // The old value is "init"
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The new value is " + strNew); // The new value is "blub"
    }
}
```